# How to specify layout in to_xml in rails 3.2.x?

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way to specify the layout option as in the respond_to method?

or is there any way to capture the output of respond_to methods output to file?

Thanks in advance !!

*UPDATE:*

Using following function to save the xml to file.

```
def generate_xml
 xml_data = self.to_xml 
 file = File.new("public/assets/xmls/#{self.id}.xml", "w")
 file.write(xml_data)
 file.close
end
```

but it only generate the default element, not as specified in show.xml file, which I can get from browser hit.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question, What are you trying to accomplish?
You can just call "layout :application" Anywhere you like f.e. in the header of the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am trying to save the output of default xml render to file using a function updated in the question. But it is not picking up the xml template.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the controller calls render

```
"/path/to/show.xml" :locals => { :xml_obj => :xml_obj }
```

In other words to generate the same result as the show action in your controller call the render action in the same fashion as you do (presumably implicitly) in the #show action of your controller.

Comment: But then how should I save the resulted xml after render?